# Bring modeless form with WindowState=wsNormal behind MdiChild?

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to show a modeless "wsNormal" WindowsState form behind a MDIChild form? I want to create a NOTE form which is always behind other forms (but always in front of the MDI form), unless you bring it to the front. E.g when you click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's technically impossible for window that is not an child of the MDI container.

The MDI children are child windows of the MDI container which is a child of the main form. If a window is in front of the main form, then it is in front of the MDI children. If it is behind the main form, then it is behind the MDI children.

Comment: Is there any other solution to set a form in front or to back of a MDIChild window? So when one MDIChild is maximized, the ohter is in "normal" state. This window should just work as a NOTE (like in MS Outlook).

Comment: I explained why it's not possible. So did Sertac. The only things that can overlap with MDI children is MDI children.

Answer (score 2):

Normally no, MDI parent is the root parent of MDI childs, you're either below the MDI parent or above. But you can set the parent of your top-level form to be the MDICLIENT.

I wouldn't suggest this approach as it possibly would have complications (maybe(?) you can achieve the same effect by tweaking some other MDI client class). But if you want to try what it would look like create a new "MDI Application" project and change the code that runs from the Help->About menu item to:

```
procedure TMainForm.HelpAbout1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
//  AboutBox.ShowModal;
  windows.SetParent(AboutBox.Handle, ClientHandle);
  AboutBox.Show;
  SetWindowPos(AboutBox.Handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOMOVE);
end;
```

Comment: Why would you do it this way? Surely if you want to put a window in the MDI container it would be simpler just to make it an MDI child?

Comment: @David - Sure. I mentioned that in the answer. This is only to answer the question.. OTOH I'm not sure I did it.. I think I'm gonna delete this one, if only you wouldn't say that's 'technically impossible'..

Comment: @David: I cannot make the NOTE window as child, because other maximized childs would be set to wsNormal, when a new NOTE is created. Since the NOTE can never be maximized.

Comment: @max - Ok, I'm not deleting the answer, see if this fits your situation.

Comment: @Sertac I qualified what I mean by technically impossible.

Comment: @David - re-parenting a top-level window is out of technical possibility?

Comment: Clearly the window needs to be a child of the MDI container if it wants to overlap the MDI children. I'm sceptical that it can work, but you know more about this stuff than I do.

Comment: @David - `ClientHandle` is the handle of the MDICLIENT, the window that's actually parenting MDI childs. I'm also skeptical that this would work. About knowing... this is rather experimental.. :)

Comment: @Sertac I'm quite familiar with `ClientHandle` having recently done some work involving docking a form to the side of the MDICLIENT. It was very messy indeed. I would certainly be interested to know if you can stuff non-MDI windows into an MDI container.

Comment: @David - Your modification makes perfect sense, +1.